# Apache - Allow access for folders starting with /

Tags: apache-httpd, configuration

I'm running apache in a linux environment. I've to serve files whose directory structure have "/." in it. Now, apache by default won't allow files with /. To remove the constraint, I've included the following entry in httpd conf.

`<DirectoryMatch "^.|/.">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</DirectoryMatch>`

But,this opens up all hidden directories under apache root. I'm trying to use a directory pattern so that it'll only allow files under this directory. For e.g. the directory path always start with /content/. The occurrence of /. can be anywhere. For e.g. 

`/content/url/test/.NET/sample/abc.html
/content/xyz/.BETA/sample/test.html`

As you can see, I'm trying to create a pattern where the rule would allow directories starting with "/content" and can having "/." in its path.
Just wondering if it's possible to have a rule like this in  option.

Comment: Your rule is correct as the dot in linux signifies the current directory.  The current directory in relation to httpd.conf is /etc/apache IIRC.  Try adding `DocumentRoot` after Googling for it

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried that but you need to use

```
DocumentRoot
```

In apaches virtualhost config (in sites-enabled, or httpd.conf) file
you need to follow this entry:

```
/content/url/test/.NET/sample/abc.html
/content/xyz/.BETA/sample/test.html

<virtualhost:*80>
  ServerAdmin whatever@whatever
  DocumentRoot {your-desired-directory {/root/file-path"/content"}
</virtualhost>
```

if you need to add / just create another entry for

```
<virtualhost:*80>
  ServerAdmin whatever@whatever
  DocumentRoot {your-desired-directory {/root/file-path"/"}
</virtualhost>
```